# Capturing and handling HTML5 video events

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-player

I'm trying to develop custom HTML5 video player. Struggling a little bit with getting my head round as to how should I handle events that I'm capturing. For example:

```
//this will work
video.oncanplay = alert("can play"); 

//this won't work
video.oncanplay = function(){
    alert("can play");
}

//but this will work
video.oncanplay = (function(){
    alert("can play");
})();
```

Is a self invoking function a right approach? Or should I try something else? Tried to read w3c documentation but failed to grasp it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add event listeners - as in this example https://gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414 - for what I want to track. You can either point all the events to a single function (which I did for that example) of attach specific ones depending on your logic

Comment: what if you want to program specific behaviour in a specific situation?

Comment: if, for instance, you want certain things to happen at certain times I control that based on the timeline - the timeupdate event for instance lets me see where the playhead is so I can (eg) turn an overlay on or off